# How to stop the first child process from being executed?

Tags: c++, fork

Aim: To design a linux shell, which shows a prompt to take input from user, creates a new process to execute that command then terminates/exits the process. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

string cmd; //global string so cmd copied to child to execute    

void HandleAsParent(){
    cout<<"Linux Shell 1.0\n";
    string s;
    while (!exitflag) {
        cout<<"myShell>";
        getline(cin,cmd); //Take user input
        fork();
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

void HandleAsChild(){
    cout<<"Executing";
    system(cmd.c_str());
}

int main() {
    pid_t p = fork();
    if(p != 0){
        HandleAsParent(); //This is parent process
    }
    else {
        HandleAsChild(); //This is child process
    }
}
```

The problem is that, because of the first fork() call in the main,

> myShell>Executing

is displayed on the first line when the program runs instead of just

> myShell>

.
I am able to understand why this is happening but cannot figure out how do I stop that first child process from being executed.
Please suggest me workarounds/solutions to my problem.

> Edit 1: This is one of my Assignment(for learning UNIX Processes)
>   questions, and It is clearly stated that the program " prompts the
>   user for a command, parses the command, and then executes it with a
>   child process "

Comment: There's nothing in the shown code that actually requires `fork()`ing. What exactly do you expect to accomplish by `fork()`ing, then executing a command in the child process without the parent waiting for it? Simply get rid of the useless forks. Problem solved.

Comment: This is still WIP, I got stuck here and didn't code any further, ofcourse, the parent will wait for the child to finish and then only proceed further(show prompt)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have edited to add a wait() statement.

Comment: Just remove the fork from main. It should only contain `int main() { HandleAsParent(); return 0; }`

Comment: @SergeBallesta then how do I run the code for child in the child process ?

Comment: Please, see my answer (it was a little bit too much for a comment). Why do you call `fork()` in `HandleAsParent()`? (I didn't quite get the intention.)

Comment: @Scheff Hi, I read your answer, I already know what you described. I am tryin to find a way to get around that. I'm calling fork() in handleAsParent() as I have taken input string in cmd and now I want to create a new process where this string will be executed using system(cmd) function call.

Comment: _I'm calling fork() in handleAsParent()_ Yeah, but without evaluating the return value of `fork()` it's somehow fruitless, isn't it? (That's why my explicit description.)

Comment: Yeah Ik, this is one of my Assignment(for learning UNIX Processes) questions, and It is clearly stated that the program " prompts the user for a command, parses the command, and then executes it with a child process "  @Scheff

Comment: What you should do is something like `if (fork() == 0) system();`. The `else` branch of this `if` may or may not `wait()` depending on whether you want to make something like foreground or background execution.

Comment: My previous comment in mind, the `fork()` in `main()` does not make sense really (as already mentioned). Btw. If parent shall `wait()` until child has finished why `fork()` at all. Simply calling `system()` would achieve this as well (also already mentioned).

Comment: @Scheff system() is a temporary solution , I actually have to use "execl" later on and wait/not-wait depending upon background/foreground. Basically, I am using system() to test stuff before moving on.

Comment: (Upvoting your comment was accident - my browser behaved strange until I reloaded.) However, this is a requirement that should've been stated in question. (So, it makes sense to upvote it, finally.)

Comment: @Scheff as for the if condition you suggested, wouldn't it still cause a child process to create and thus "Executing" to be displayed (which was the original issue)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178199/discussion-between-abhishek-ranjan-and-scheff).

Comment: There is a big difference between `exec()` family and `system()`: `exec()` functions replace the code of current process after successfully loading a new program. Hence, if you want to continue the program which called `exec()` a `fork()` is mandatory. This is not the case for `system()`. (I guess, it already contains a combination of `fork()`, `exec()`, and `wait()`.)

Comment: `Executing` is printed by `HandleAsChild()`. I already told you that I don't get the intention of the `fork()` in `main()` (after I've understood what the `fork()` in `HandleAsParent()` is dedicated for.)

Comment: Should we continue over Telegram ?so that we can have instant replies ?

Comment: Actually, I've still to do a little bit of professional work where I'm paid for. ;-) May be, think about what I've told you. IMHO, it contains enough to start from.

Comment: Okay, so you know the reason for fork in HandleParent(). Let me explain you why it is there in main. After the fork() from HandleParent(), the child process starts execution from main() (right?). So how will it know that it has to do command processig rather than showing a prompt?  fork()'s return value !!!. This is why it is there in main().

Comment: Btw. these functions are well documented. There are lots of examples. In the past 1,5 years, I've been member, I can remember multiple questions about similar topics. (It seems to be a common assignment question everywhere.) So, google must show everything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already guessed, `system()` probably uses a combination of `fork()`, `exec()` and `wait()`. Out of curiosity, I googled for source code and found one on woboq.org: [glibc/sysdeps/posix/system.c](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/system.c.html).

This in mind, using `system()`, the required child process "comes for free". So, I got this minimal sample:

```
#include <iostream>

void callCmd(const std::string &cmd)
{
  system(cmd.c_str());
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "My Linux Shell 1.0\n"
    << "Type exit[Enter] to exit.\n";
  for (;;) {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);
    if (input == "exit") return 0;
    callCmd(input);
  }
}
```

Compiled and tested on [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o mycroShell mycroShell.cc 

$ ./mycroShell 
My Linux Shell 1.0
Type exit[Enter] to exit.
> echo "Hello"
Hello
> exit

$
```

After getting this running, the `system()` call in `callCmd()` can be replaced by `fork()`/`exec()`/`wait()` without the necessity to change anything else.

---

A simplified version could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void callCmd(const std::string &input)
{
  // the pre-processing: split the input into command and arguments
  std::string cmdArgs = input;
  std::vector<char*> args;
  char *cmd = &cmdArgs[0];
  args.push_back(cmd);
  for (char *c = cmd; *c; ++c) {
    if (*c == ' ') {
      *c = '\0'; args.push_back(c + 1);
    }
  }
  args.push_back(nullptr); // append terminator
  // simple replacement of system() (not that sophisticated)
  int ret = fork();
  if (ret < 0) { // failure
    std::cerr << "Failed to execute '" << cmd << "'!\n";
  } else if (ret == 0) { // child
    execvp(cmd, args.data());
  } else { // parent
    waitpid(ret, nullptr, 0);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "My Linux Shell 1.1\n"
    << "Type exit[Enter] to exit.\n";
  for (;;) {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::string input; std::getline(std::cin, input);
    if (input == "exit") return 0;
    callCmd(input);
  }
}
```

Compiled and tested on [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10 again:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -o mycroShell mycroShell.cc 

$ ./mycroShell
My Linux Shell 1.1
Type exit[Enter] to exit.
> /usr/bin/echo "Hello"
"Hello"
> exit

$
```

Notes:

1. IMHO, the most tricky part of this is to prepare a proper argument vector for `execvp`.
2. I tried with `echo "Hello"` as well and it worked. This surprised me a bit as `echo` is a bash built-in command. I assume that it found `/usr/bin/echo` and used it as well as in my above output.
3. The error handling is rather poor – something which should be extended for serious applications.

Comment: OHMYGOD, does the forked function start from where the fork occour or from main() ??

Comment: As I described in my (now deleted) text. `fork()` returns into parent and child process. I.e. both processes continue exactly after `fork()`.

Comment: That's why they called it `fork()` (like the fork used to eat). ;-)